# How to Replace number with asterisk in crystal report formula?

Tags: sql, asp.net, encryption, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I want show the encrypted Number in report like this:

Number : 7890123478

I want to show this as an output result:  *******478

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I don't know about the exact syntax in Crystal Reports, but the logic is simple: `'*******' || cast(mynumber modulo 1000 as char(3))`

Comment: @dnoeth That comment is borderline brilliant, and it might even make sense to post here it just as a generic approach.  My guess is that Crystal Reports would support it.

Answer (score -1):

For sql this query can help you.

```
declare @ph varchar(10) = '7890123478'

select replicate('*',len(@ph)-3)+ right(@ph,3)
```